# Possible bug in jQuery's post() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

(I am french and very bad in English so I am sorry for it.)

I have a small problem, so I will show my code because it is very strange.

The first code will run without problem and ajax is good but the second doesn't run. Only one change in the second. I haven't the alert() method.

So let me show you :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").click(function(){
        $.post('game/PlayersProcessing.php',{// Un script PHP que l'on va créer juste après
                username : $("#username").val(),  // Nous récupérons la valeur de nos inputs que l'on fait passer à connexion.php
                password : $("#password").val()
            },
            function(data,status){
                $("#form").html(data);
        });
        alert('kkj');
    });
});
```

and now look the second

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").click(function(){
        $.post('game/PlayersProcessing.php',{// Un script PHP que l'on va créer juste après
                username : $("#username").val(),  // Nous récupérons la valeur de nos inputs que l'on fait passer à connexion.php
                password : $("#password").val()
            },
            function(data,status){
                $("#form").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you a lot for your help I imagine it is very easy but I am a beginner and I haven't good reflex for the moment.

Thanks ! :)

Comment: How do you detect it "doesn't run", as you say is  the same code and the alert is outside the function.

Comment: with alert my code run, my text change with the content of PlayersProcessing.php. But without the alert nothing change. And I don't understand why..

I have a div with id="form" and the content if the code run, is replace by a sentence from PlayersProcessing.php. All is good with alert but nothing without.

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Have you checked in a network logging tool like chrome's or firefox's if the request is actually performed?

Comment: you can use developer tools with F12 in Chrome or IE.  Look at the console window to see if there's a javascript error.  It could be as simple as needing to change the relative path to an absolute one: `/game/PlayersProcessing.php`.  We'll be able to better help you with some sort of error message or debugging effort.

Comment: I have checked with error consol of firefox and there are no difference between the two code. There is just one problem

"GET 
http://127.0.0.1/projects/oldwar/js/menu.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 26ms]" but I think it doesn't matter because I have this error with each code.

Comment: I have no problem with javascript code for the console of firefox

Comment: problem is becomming very complicated...
With google chrome, each code run but my page is reload just after. So result doesn't stay on the page.

With alert in firefox, the page doesn't reload itself

Comment: Then your problem is that `#register` is acting like a submit button of a form, to avoid that in the `<form>`add `<form onsubmit="return false"> and make sure `#register`is a `<button type=submit>` and not a `<input type=submit>`

Comment: I found !! and oscargilfc I just read your comment so you have right. I had a  <input type=submit>  so now i have a <input type="button"> so all is good. In fact, submit is for a form so firefox and chrome reload page, button haven't default behaviour so all is good now. Thanks a lot for all your help ! How can I close? :p

Answer (score 0):

Test ?

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```